# Access Select Query - Include blank values

Tags: ms-access

Good afternoon,
I am creating a database for handling safety at my workplace.
I want to create a system where the user can raise a toolbox talk and through filters produce a list of employees who need to participate because they either belong to a certain department, certain competency or both.
To set the scene, an employee can be assigned multiple departments and multiple competencies in which case my select query: Query:ToolboxTalk works fine.
However there are occasions where an employee will be assigned to a department but maybe no competency. When this happens, my query does not return that employee because of the null value.

My question is this:
How can I make my query include null values or should I be going about this a different way?

Please see screenshot of my query in design view and SQL below:

```
SELECT tblEmployees.EmployeeID, IIf(IsNull([LastName]),IIf(IsNull([FirstName]),[FirstName]),IIf(IsNull([FirstName]),[LastName],[FirstName] & " " & [LastName])) AS [Employee Name], tblEmployees.Gender, tblDepartments.DepartmentID, tblDepartments.Department, tblCompetencies.CompetencyID, tblCompetencies.CompetencyDescription, tblEmployeesDepartments.EmployeesDepartmentID, tblEmployeesCompetencies.EmployeeCompetencyID
FROM (tblEmployees INNER JOIN (tblCompetencies INNER JOIN tblEmployeesCompetencies ON tblCompetencies.CompetencyID = tblEmployeesCompetencies.CompetencyID) ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblEmployeesCompetencies.EmployeeID) INNER JOIN (tblDepartments INNER JOIN tblEmployeesDepartments ON tblDepartments.DepartmentID = tblEmployeesDepartments.DepartmentID) ON tblEmployees.EmployeeID = tblEmployeesDepartments.EmployeeID
WHERE (((tblEmployees.EmploymentStatus)="Active"));
```

[Query-Design View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJsuv.jpg)

If there is any info I have neglected to include, please let me know and Ill endeavour to add it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is what a `Left Join` is for. Look up some SQL tutorial for examples.

Comment: Thank you Gustav. Your suggestion of a left join sent me down the path to success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to adjust query to left join with normalised table structure.
Refer picture and sql.
[Query design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRuas.jpg)
[Query SQL view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chI1j.jpg)